# Where is the second part of navigation video in PR2 Beta Training Workshop on ROS & PR2?

Tags: ros, navigation, video

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [PR2BetaTraining](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Events/PR2BetaTraining/Videos/Tuesday)

I can find the first part of navigation video (1/4).

Where is the other parts of navigation video such as 2/4,3/4,4/4?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12416/where-is-the-second-part-of-navigation-video-in-pr2-beta-training-workshop-on-ros-&-pr2?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is only one part to that video.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-12-23**:
indeed, the rest of the tutorial was all hands on coding, so there was no presentation to show